# How to mix matplotlib.scatter and seabon.regplot?

Tags: seaborn

I want a scatter plot with points as circles and radius of circles in function of the weight. 
I am fitting that with numpy.polyfit.

Then I want a confident level on that. I can use regplot but he has his own fitting method, without the possibility (right ?) to give him my own weights.

Can I join both methods ? Two ways for that :

- apply a confident level with polyfit
- apply my own weights with seaborn.regplot (instead of robust=true)

An example, fit with the confident level like in plot 1 and take into account weights like in plot 2 :

```
heights = np.array([50,52,53,54,58,60,62,64,66,67, 68,70,72,74,76,55,50,45,65])
weights = 
np.array([25,50,55,75,80,85,50,65,85,55,45,45,50,75,95,65,50,40,45])
weights_2 = np.array([85,55,45,45,50,25,50,55,75,80,85,50,65,75,95,65,50,40,45])

sns.regplot(heights,weights, color ='blue')
```

and

```
heights = np.array([50,52,53,54,58,60,62,64,66,67, 68,70,72,74,76,55,50,45,65])
weights = np.array([25,50,55,75,80,85,50,65,85,55,45,45,50,75,95,65,50,40,45])
weights_2 = np.array([600,550,45,45,50,25,50,55,500,80,85,50,65,75,95,65,50,40,45])

plt.scatter(heights,weights,s=weights_2)
res=np.polyfit(heights,weights,1,w=weights_2)
res_plot=np.poly1d(res)
plt.plot(heights,res_plot(heights),color="black")
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is the desired outcome here?

Comment: Make : sns.regplot(heights,weights, color ='blue', w=weights_2) but I can't use "w=" with regplot (right ?)

Comment: No you can't. So it would be better to tell what the desired *outcome* is.

Comment: I want a simple way to plot a confident level ? (on a fit where i use my own weights on my points)